# How to merge two rows in table

Tags: tables

My code is like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\caption{Main concept classes }
\small
\begin{tabular}
    {m{3cm}<{\centering}m{2cm}<{\centering}m{7.5cm}<{\centering}}
\hline
\textbf{Class}& \textbf{Symbol} & \textbf{Description}  \\
\hline Combined Capability & CC& Combined capabilities
 \\ \hline  Simple Capability& SC & Simple Capability  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\label{label:1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

It will be like this:
[image]

Will it be possible to merge the column to make the table look like this?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try this code using `multirow` to merge two cells into a multi-row cell.

(Put `\label` next to `\caption`)

[image: b]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!ht]
        \centering\sffamily
        \caption{Main concept}  \label{label:1}
        \small
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
        \begin{tabular}{lll}
            \hline
            \textbf{Class}                  & \textbf{Symbol}    & \textbf{Description}  \\ \hline 
            \multirow{ 2}{*}{Capability}    & CC                 & Combined Capability  \\ \cline{2-3}
                                            & SC                 & Simple Capability\\ \hline
        \end{tabular}       
    \end{table}     
\end{document}
```

**Optional**

Adding  `\usepackage{booktabs}` you can get nicer rules.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage{booktabs} % nicer rules

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!ht]
        \centering\sffamily
        \caption{Main concept}\label{label:1}
        \small
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}% expand the cells
        \begin{tabular}{lll}
            \toprule
            \textbf{Class}                  & \textbf{Symbol}    & \textbf{Description}  \\ \midrule
            \multirow{ 2}{*}{Capability}    & CC                 & Combined Capability  \\ \cline{2-3}
                                            & SC                 & Simple Capability\\
          \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        
    \end{table}     
\end{document}
```

[image: c]

Answer (score 3):

With the use of package `nicematrix` - the `Block{2-1}` represents a multi row command consisting `{2rows-1column}`

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \caption{Main concept}
        \NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits = 3pt}
    
        \begin{NiceTabular}{ccc}
        \Hline
        Class                    &Symbol    &Description  \\    \Hline
        \Block{2-1}{Capability}  & CC       &Combined Capability \\ \Hline
                                 & SC       & Simple Capability\\ \Hline
    \end{NiceTabular}
    \end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

A second example with the use of little color to emphasise the header row - this eliminates the need of horizontal rules or `\Hline`

Color `blue` is added to row one with the syntax

```
        \CodeBefore
        \rowcolor{blue!50}{1}
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \caption{Main concept}
        \NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits = 3pt}
        
        \begin{NiceTabular}{ccc}
            \CodeBefore
            \rowcolor{blue!50}{1}           
            \Body
            \RowStyle{\bfseries}
            Class                         &Symbol   &Description  \\                
            \Block{2-1}{Capability}       & CC      &Combined Capability \\ 
                                          & SC      & Simple Capability\\ \Hline
        \end{NiceTabular}
    
    \end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that employs the `multirow` and `booktabs` packages.

Two comments. First, the first argument of `\multirow` need not be integer-valued. Second, it's ok to use the basic `c` column type here instead of `m{...}<{\centering}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\usepackage{multirow} % for "\multirow" macro

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Main concept\strut}
\begin{tabular}{@{} ccc @{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Class} & \textbf{Symbol} & \textbf{Description}  \\
\midrule
\multirow{2.3}{*}{Capability} & CC & Combined Capability \\
\cmidrule(l){2-3}
                              & SC & Simple Capability   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```